# Stack table rows within for loop in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, concatenation

I have a table T=rand(8,3). The first row is selected by default. The successive rows are selected if a condition is met.

```
T=rand(8,3)
Tn=T(1,:)
for i=1:size(T,1)
      if sum(T,2)<1.5
          Tn(i,:)=cat(1, Tn, T(i,:))
      end
end
```

I am getting error in stacking up the  rows. Various ways tried but no success.

Comment: Are you sure `if sum(T, 2) < 1.5` is the correct `if` statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution**

The best approach to this problem, would be:

```
Tn = T(sum(T,2) < 1.5,:)
```

Notice that that solution doesn't take the first row by default. If you want it to take it regardless to whether the condition is met or not, use:

```
Tn = T([1 ; sum(T(2:end,:),2)] < 1.5,:)
```

**Result**

```
T =

0.8055    0.9787    0.5216
0.5767    0.7127    0.0967
0.1829    0.5005    0.8181
0.2399    0.4711    0.8175
0.8865    0.0596    0.7224
0.0287    0.6820    0.1499
0.4899    0.0424    0.6596
0.1679    0.0714    0.5186

sum(T,2) =

2.3058
1.3861
1.5015
1.5286
1.6686
0.8605
1.1919
0.7580

Tn =

0.5767    0.7127    0.0967
0.0287    0.6820    0.1499
0.4899    0.0424    0.6596
0.1679    0.0714    0.5186
```

**How to make your code work**

To make your code work you need to fix the if condition as well as the assignment line:

```
sumT = sum(T,2)
for i=1:size(T,1)
    if sumT(i)<1.5
        Tn = [Tn; T(i,:)];
    end
end
```